# How may Myanmar modify the constitution and keep off the military from politics?

Tags: constitution, myanmar

In January 2019, the National League for Democracy pushed for constitutional reform, but was unsuccessful because any changes required 75% approval in the legislature, and 25% of seats are reserved for the military.

Details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Myanmar_general_election

Miss Suu Kyi's party has won 79.5% seats in the bicameral legislature. 396/498 = 79.5%

Details: https://www.voanews.com/east-asia-pacific/aung-san-suu-kyi-nld-win-second-landslide-election-myanmar

1. Does it mean they can change the constitution now? (79.5% > 75%)
2. Or, does it mean they still can't change it? As 25% is reserved for military. So, 79.5% of 75% = 59.625%. Is 100% of the 75% necessary to change the constitution?

Which is correct : 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second of your statements is true; elected representatives are unable to amend the constitution unilaterally. An amendment to the constitution has to be approved by *more than* 75% of representatives, and in certain cases must also be subsequently confirmed in a nation-wide referendum, and be supported by more than half of those eligible to vote - see section 436 of the [2008 Myanmar Constitution](http://www.myanmar-law-library.org/IMG/pdf/constitution_de_2008.pdf).

As the constitution also guarantees that 25% of seats in both the lower and upper houses (Pyithu Hluttaw and Amyotha Hluttaw) are controlled by the military, in sections 109(b) and 141(b), the military has a veto over constitutional change - an amendment to the constitution cannot go ahead without the votes of at least some of the unelected Defence
Services personnel serving in the legislature.

For a recent example of this power, consider the vote against the amendments proposed in 2015, which would have lowered the threshold of representatives required to pass a constitutional amendment to 70%, as well as altering the qualifications for President which currently block Aung San Suu Kyi from that role. When the proposals were defeated, San Suu Kyi had the [following response](https://www.usnews.com/news/world/articles/2015/06/25/myanmars-parliament-blocks-changes-to-constitution):

> "I am not surprised with the result," Suu Kyi told reporters after the
> vote. **"This makes it very clear that the constitution can never be
> changed if the military representatives are opposed."** She said she
> didn't see the vote as a loss, since the result had been anticipated,
> so her supporters should not lose hope.